# What is the difference between Copied context output format and Unified context output format while taking diff?

Tags: linux, diff

What is the difference between Copied context output format and Unified context output format when taking a diff?

```
diff -NBur dir1/ dir2/  
diff -NBcr dir1/ dir2/
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently you've misread the manual.  The `-u` flag is for *unified* context, not Unicode and `-c` is for *copied* context, not 'Context format':

`-c  -C NUM  --context[=NUM]
              Output NUM (default 3) lines of copied context.`

`-u  -U NUM  --unified[=NUM]
              Output NUM (default 3) lines of unified context.`

The most straightforward way to find out what is the difference, is to try it out:

```
$ cat >1
line
diff 
more
^D
$ cat >2
line 
ffid
more
^D
```

```
$ diff -c 1 2
*** 1   2010-12-14 09:08:48.019797000 +0200
--- 2   2010-12-14 09:08:56.029797001 +0200
***************
*** 1,3 ****
  line
! diff
  more
--- 1,3 ----
  line
! ffid
  more
```

```
$ diff -u 1 2
--- 1   2010-12-14 09:08:48.019797000 +0200
+++ 2   2010-12-14 09:08:56.029797001 +0200
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 line
-diff
+ffid
 more
```

Do you get what's the difference?

Comment: i admit the mistake i made in telling __unified__ context format. But the man page of diif says -c as __context output format__.

Comment: __Do you get what's the difference?__ i could see only difference in the symbols used. In one it is __*__ and in the other it is __+__. Does it imply something else?

Comment: @Sen: that, plus with `-c` you have two blocks of differing text, where `!` marks the lines which differ, and with `-u` there is only one, where `+` and `-` before line denote versions of the differing line: minus when line in `1` is missing from `2`, plus when line in `2` was added to `1`.  Is this clear enough now?